# Using regular expressions in tidyr::extract

Tags: r, regex, tidyr

I am working with 3D motion-capture data. This means I have 3 columns (X,Y,Z) of joint coordinates for several joints in the body (e.g. the three columns describing the position of the left knee joint center are: LKX,LKY,LKZ).

My end goal is to plot at least 9 joint centers, and I believe the only way to achieve this is to transform my wide format dataframe into a long one.

As you can tell, I am trying to transform many sets of jointcenters ending with either: X,Y or Z. Therefore, I try to use regular expressions within tidyr:extract, but I just can´t get the code right.

```
df_wide <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:2, each=10),
  JN = rep(1:2, each=5),
  Frame = rep(1:5, 4),
  System = rep(1:2, 10),
  RKX = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  RKY = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  RKZ = rep(1:10+rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5), 2),
  LHeX = rep(1:10-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  LHeY = rep(1:10-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2),
  LHeZ = rep(1:10-rnorm(10,mean=1,sd=0.5),2))

head(df_wide, 2)
  ID JN Frame System      RKX      RKY      RKZ        LHeX       LHeY      LHeZ
1  1  1     1      1 1.332827 2.068720 2.295742 -0.02336031 -0.3011227 -1.212326
2  1  1     2      2 3.570076 3.306799 3.136177  2.08828231  1.9226740  2.106496
```

I wish to obtain this result:

```
   ID JN Frame System joint         X         Y         Z
1   1  1     1      1    RK  1.440103  2.221676  1.621871
2   1  1     1      1   LHe  3.537940  3.060948  2.856955
```

Here is my latest (of many) attempts. It has two problems; 1) extract only produces NA; 2) spread returns "Error: Duplicate identifiers for rows" I suspect this is related to the problem with extract.

```
df_3D <- df_wide %>%
 gather(keys, values, -ID, -JN, -Frame, -System)%>% 
  extract(keys, c("X", "Y", "Z", "joint"), "(X$) (Y$) (Z$) ([A-Z].$)")%>% 
  spread(X, values)
```

---

I have found several good questions and answers regarding the transformation, but none of them specifically target the use of regular expressions.

Comment: @Gregor I think it's referring to `tidyr::extract`, it's easy to get confused between what's in `dplyr` specifically and what's in the broader `tidyverse`

Comment: Constantly confused. Got tripped up earlier because rlang is using `:=` but I assumed `data.table`

Comment: @Marius - Reading your comment I realized I made a mistake. I always thought extract was a part of dplyr, but [here](https://rdrr.io/cran/tidyr/man/) I see that it is in fact, as you wrote, a part of tidyr. Post is edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach is a little off. Each element of the `keys` column once you've gathered has the structure `<Joint><Coord>`, so you want something like:

```
df_wide %>%
    gather(keys, values, -ID, -JN, -Frame, -System) %>%
    extract(keys, c("Joint", "Coord"), "(.*)(X|Y|Z)$") %>%
    spread(Coord, values)
```

The regex I've used here captures anything in the first group (since I don't know all the possible joint names), then X or Y or Z as the final character in the second group. There are lots of other regexes that would achieve the same thing.

Output:

```
   ID JN Frame System Joint          X          Y           Z
1   1  1     1      1   LHe  0.1344259 -0.2927277  0.05375166
2   1  1     1      1    RK  1.8083539  2.4053498  2.32899399
3   1  1     2      2   LHe  1.1777492  1.1780538  0.96549849
4   1  1     2      2    RK  3.2254236  2.4100235  2.79816371
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works so well. I am always amazed at how much a few signs of regex can achieve. Can you recommend any sources for learning the regex better? I often find it challenging to capture a specific pattern such as the one in this example. I have used this [link](http://stat545.com/block022_regular-expression.html) until now.

Comment: I learned regular expressions by reading [this book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). There are probably quicker and easier ways to learn, but I can only speak to what I did.

Comment: Thank you -  The book description doesn't specifically mention R. Are the regex expressions identical across languages?

Comment: @SteenHarsted: yes, as long as you remember to escape your backslashes properly it's the same underlying expression language. `stringr` and the `tidyverse` use perl-style regular expressions, which are used across many languages. Base R uses a slightly simpler version with less features by default, but allows perl-style expressions as well.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to gather your data into a super long format, then split out the dimension, then spread THAT data back out into your X, Y, and Z columns:

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)

df2  <- df_wide %>% 
  # leave the other columns
  gather( jointid, position, -ID, -JN, -Frame, -System ) %>% 
  # insert a seperator to make it easier to split the X/Y/Z from the joint name
  mutate(jointid = str_replace( jointid, "X|Y|Z", ";\\0")) %>% 
  # split the joint name and the dimension apart
  tidyr::separate(jointid, c('joint', 'dim'), sep = ";" ) %>% 
  # spread the joint and position apart into 3 columns
  spread(dim, position)
```

Comment: Also a very nice solution - Thank you!